# Limite de itens no "foreach"

Tags: php, loop

Tenho um código que pega as imagens da pasta `images/FotosdoWhatsAPP`, porém está exibindo todas as imagens, gostaria de exibir somente uma quantidade X
(ex: 5 imagens).

```
<?php  
$dirname = "images/FotosWhatsApp/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,JPEG,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '
<a href="'.$image.'" data-at-1920="'.$image.'">
<div class="div-thumbnail-portfolio" style="background-image: url('.$image.');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover; background-position: center center; " class="thumbnail-detalhe">

</div>
</a>
    ';

    /*<a href="'.$image.'" rel="gallery" class="fresco" data-fresco-group="example">
    <img src="'.$image.'" style="background-image: url('.$image.');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover; background-position: center center; " class="thumbnail-detalhe"/>
</a>*/
}

?>
```

Comment: Leia sobre a função [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem algumas forma:

Não use o `foreach`, use o `for`:

```
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,JPEG,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE);
for ($i = 0; count($images); $i++) {
    echo '
<a href="'.$images[i].'" data-at-1920="'.$images[i].'">
```

Crie um contador e coloque uma condição (acho ineficiente e feio):

```
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,JPEG,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE);
$i = 0;
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '
<a href="'.$image.'" data-at-1920="'.$image.'">
...
if (++$i > 4) break;
```

Use uma condição na chave do *array* (acho ineficiente e feio):

```
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,JPEG,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($images as $key => $image) {
    echo '
<a href="'.$image.'" data-at-1920="'.$image.'">
...
if ($key > 4) break;
```

Limite o *array* antes de entrar no laço (compensa em alguns casos):

```
$images = array_slice(glob($dirname."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,JPEG,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE), 4);
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '
<a href="'.$image.'" data-at-1920="'.$image.'">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/LimitItemsFor.php).

Comment: Maravilha testei a 3º opção e funcionou certinho. Obrigado ai @Maniero

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é aplicar em conjunto as classes [`DirectoryIterator`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php) e [`LimitIterator`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.limititerator.php):

```
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('./data');
$firstFiveFiles = new LimitIterator($directory, 0, 5);

foreach ($firstFiveFiles as $file) {
    ...
}
```

Mas obviamente que a complexidade disso para substituir um mero `if` costuma inviabilizar a solução. Fica a seu critério também adaptar o uso de `DirectoryIterator`, ou análogo, para selecionar apenas os arquivos desejados.

Comment: Oi Anderson obrigado ai pelo feedback. Muito boa sua dica também